# Difference in overflow scrollbar position in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, overflow

I have a very basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mstrater/jv1ofzkm/) that's showing different behaviors in IE and Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div id="viewer">
    <div id="actionsPaneContainer">
        <div id="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
#viewer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #cac;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#actionsPaneContainer {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    left: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#content {
    white-space: no-wrap;
    background-color: #afc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 3000px;
}
```

Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17843:

[image: Overflow in IE]

Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m (**Notice the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom**)

[image: Overflow in Chrome]

Why is this happening and how do I correct it so they both function like it does on IE now?

Edit:
Here's an even simpler [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mstrater/pk561eyg/) that demonstrates the issue. It appears to be a difference in how `overflow:auto;` is computed.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        CSS is fun!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 90px;
}
#content {
    background-color: #bad;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

If you change it to be `overflow:scroll;` they both behave the same.